# Complexity economics and computational economics books recommendation

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for books in [complexity economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_economics) and/or [agent-based computational economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_computational_economics).

What are some good introductory and advanced books in these fields?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by complexity?

Comment: this is the [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_economics#:~:text=Complexity%20economics%20is%20the%20application,to%20the%20problems%20of%20economics.&text=It%20uses%20computational%20and%20mathematical,'agents'%20in%20the%20economy.) about it

Comment: I think Steve Keen would probably identify his Minksy model with complexity (non-equilibirum) economics. Have you seen his lectures on Minsky software/modelling?

Comment: no, thanks for the suggestion!